# Parse Issue Cound not build module 'Firebase'

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, firebase

I installed the Firebase in my project as shown by Firebase guidelines and installed it successfully.

when i am importing `Firebase` and `FirebaseMessaging` in my `AppDelegate.m` it gives

```
Parse Issue
could not build module 'Firebase'
```

I tried turning on **Allow Non-modular Includes In Framework Modules** but no luck.

i also closed the workspace and restarted the Xcode And Mac as well.

**Note : I am using Xcode 6.3 installed on OS X Yosemite, version 10.10.3**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I upgraded Xcode 6.3 to the latest version 7.3.1 and that solved my problem.